# Why does updating Garageband 6.0.5 to 10 cost money?

Tags: macos, mac-appstore, garageband

I have Garageband 6.0.5. Why does updating to Garageband 10 (next version, don't get fooled by numbers) cost money? I thought updates were free!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you bought garageband 6, you cannot update to the new version because it was released as a new program, not an update.

Comment: Oh... I never knew that.